# Game Center sign in dialog not opening second time

Tags: ios, game-center

When launching an app I'm opening a Game center sign in dialog.It works first time. but when user presses cancel button it hides. and then clicking on the button that opens ui of leaderboard it doesn't show sign in dialog although I call sign in method if user is not signed in. Here's both methods...

```
bool GameSharing::signInPlayer(){
    GKLocalPlayer *player = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    bool signedIn=false;
    [player authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        //Just relax and do nothing
    }];
    if (player.isAuthenticated) {

        signedIn = true;
    }

    return  signedIn;
}

void GameSharing::openGameCenterLeaderboardsUI(int lId){
    NSLog(@"Open Leaderboard UI");
    if(iosLeaderboardIds.size() >= lId){
        if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"not authenticated");
            signInPlayer();
        }else{
            NSLog(@"authenticated");
            AppController* appController = (AppController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

            GKLeaderboardViewController* gkController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            gkController.leaderboardIdentifier = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:iosLeaderboardIds.at(lId).c_str()];
            gkController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
            gkController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
            gkController.leaderboardDelegate = appController;

            [appController.viewController presentModalViewController:gkController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe there is some kind of delay before it pops up again? Maybe the functionality is designed so it shall only pop up once a day, unless the app is restarted. Just a guess.